# How can I close the PrintPreviewDialog once the printing is complete?

Tags: vb.net

As a new programmer in VB, I struggled to get my print routine working. Searching through a number of sources I developed the hybrid below which is working to print a simple .txt file. My question sounds like a simple one but I've learned nothing is simple in printing. How do I get the PrintPreviewDialog to close once the printing is complete?

```
    Private Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrint.Click

    Try
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings =
        PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings
        If PageSetupDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            PrintDocument1.DefaultPageSettings =
            PageSetupDialog1.PageSettings
            PrintPreviewDialog1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 600)
            PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Printing Operation Failed" & vbCrLf &
        ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Static MyNewAcctFile As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(strErrorFile)
    Dim printFont As New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim charsFitted As Integer
    Dim linesFilled As Integer
    e.Graphics.MeasureString(MyNewAcctFile, printFont, New SizeF(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height), Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic, charsFitted, linesFilled)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(MyNewAcctFile, printFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

    MyNewAcctFile = MyNewAcctFile.Substring(charsFitted)

    If MyNewAcctFile <> "" Then
        e.HasMorePages = True
    Else
        e.HasMorePages = False
        MyNewAcctFile = IO.File.ReadAllText(strErrorFile)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When you print the Document, the PrintController is replaced by a [PrintControllerWithStatusDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.printcontrollerwithstatusdialog) object, which, among other things, determines the state of the Print operation. When used for preview, `PrintController.IsPreview = true`, the opposite when you send the Document to a Printer. You can subscribe to the `PrintDocument.EndPrint` event, cast `sender` to `PrintDocument`, check whether `PrintController.IsPreview = false`: call `PrintPreviewDialog1.Close()` (it's just a Form) if it is.

Comment: For a *fancier effect*, you could make the handler async, then `await Task.Delay(1000)
printPreviewDialog1.Close()`, so it won't close as soon as you press the Print Button.

Comment: If you instead mean that you want to close the Preview dialog when *the paper comes out of the Printer* (or a PDF is written to disc), the you have to monitor the Print Job you started. So, move to the other side of the Print process. On your app's side, the document is completed when it's been sent to the printer driver.

Comment: Thanks for these comments/suggestions. They helped me to understand the printing process more clearly than Microsoft Docs could. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect to see something more like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private FileName As String
    Private txtFileContents As String

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
        FileName = "C:\Users\mikes\Documents\SomeFile.txt"
        txtFileContents = IO.File.ReadAllText(FileName)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        If txtFileContents.Length > 0 Then
            Using printFont As New Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular)
                Dim charsFitted As Integer
                Dim linesFilled As Integer
                e.Graphics.MeasureString(txtFileContents, printFont, New SizeF(e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height), Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic, charsFitted, linesFilled)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(txtFileContents, printFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, Drawing.StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

                txtFileContents = txtFileContents.Substring(charsFitted)
                e.HasMorePages = (txtFileContents.Length > 0)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_EndPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.EndPrint
        If Not PrintDocument1.PrintController.IsPreview Then
            PrintPreviewDialog1.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments. They made me understand the printing process more clearly.